# With CSS; how to style the non-overflowing element to span 100% of parent?

Tags: css, width, overflow

I'm trying to have the `Non overflowing DIV` to have the width of the parent.

```css
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  overflow: auto;
}

.parent .child-1 {
    width: 800px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

.parent .child-2 {
  background-color: lightyellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-1">Overflowing DIV</div>
  <div class="child-2">Non Overflowing DIV</div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: It's already the case, what do you mean ?

Comment: it's already having the width of the parent which is 300px. You probably want it to have the width of the other child element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you try to do ?

```css
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  overflow: auto;
  display:grid; 
  grid-auto-rows:min-content;
}

.parent .child-1 {
    width: 800px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

.parent .child-2 {
  background-color: lightyellow; 
  
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-1">Overflowing DIV</div>
  <div class="child-2">Non Overflowing DIV<!-- but does fit to the widest--></div>
</div>
```

get all children fit to the widest one ?

Grid can be used to recalculate width avalaible on each rows. *(no need of a grid-area or template here, it's a single column, only rows can be shrinked to their own height via [`grid-auto-rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-rows).)*

---

As commented By Temani Afif , `align-content: start` does the job too to shrink rows to their content.

```css
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  overflow: auto;
  display:grid; 
  align-content: start;
}

.parent .child-1 {
    width: 800px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

.parent .child-2 {
  background-color: lightyellow; 
  
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-1">Overflowing DIV</div>
  <div class="child-2">Non Overflowing DIV<!-- but does fit to the widest--></div>
</div>
```

Comment: or `align-content: start;` instead of the min-content

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes, that works too, `grid-auto-flow` deserves to be known also ;)